# PHP youtube API v3 cant unset array key

Tags: php, arrays, youtube

```
      require_once ('../google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');
      require_once ('../google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php');        
                   try {
                    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
                      'q' => $value,
                      'maxResults' => $maxRes,
                      'videoCategoryId' => '10',
                      'type' => 'video'
                    ));

                  foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $key => $searchResult) {
                      switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
                        case 'youtube#video':

              unset($searchResult[$key]);

                  .....
```

this is the output from youtube api v3 search list.

```
[items] Array
        (
            [0] Array
                (

             )
            [1] Array
                (

             )
          etc...
```

Cant unset youtube item array ?

EG :
  unset($searchResponse['items'][$key]);
still output that video.
what i doing wrong ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate over `$searchResponse['items']` then item from this array should be removed:

```
unset($searchResponse['items'][$key]);
```

Comment: Sorry not working already tried this. even unset($searchResponse); not working.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your code only unsets the `$key` offset of the local `$searchResult` variable, which exists only locally in your `foreach` loop. You need to unset it by calling `unset($searchResponse['items'][$key])` or change your loop to read `foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $key => &$searchResult)`

Comment: Sorry not working already tried this. even unset($searchResponse); not working.

Comment: Is this code inside a function or a method of some kind?

Comment: This is youtube API v3. [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search_by_keyword) . its inside function

Comment: Is the `$searchResponse` created inside the function, or passed to it by reference / globally?

Comment: Inside the function, you don't see in my question ?